# How to parse tables without classes and keep grouping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the following url http://www.trimslabs.com/mic/300.htm for IUPAC, MIC, and Organism strain. I've been able to do so to some extent, although I can't figure out a way to keep the results grouped together. Here's what I've got so far..

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
myurl = 'http://www.trimslabs.com/mic/300.htm'
uClient = uReq(myurl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
#grab IUPACs
tables = page_soup.findAll("table")
table = tables[0]
IUPACS = []
for i in range (1, 454, 3):
    IUPACs = tables[i].find(text = "IUPAC").findNext('td').get_text(",",     strip = True)
    print(IUPACs)
for i in range (455, 661, 3):
    IUPACs_two = tables[i].find(text = "IUPAC").findNext('td').get_text(",", strip = True)
    print(IUPACs_two)
#grab organism names
organism_list = page_soup.findAll("i")
org = organism_list[1]
for org in organism_list:
    organism = org.text
    print(organism)
#get the MIC numbers
for org in organism_list:
    numbers = org.findNext('td').get_text(",", strip = True)
    print(numbers)
```

this will print most the stuff I want, but I completely lose the information about what antibiotic (IUPAC) number their associated with. Realizing that each antibiotic has 3 tables, I've also tried the following

```
chem_tables = []
name_tables = []
org_tables = []
results_tables = []
for i in range (0, 451, 3):
    # 1.  Establish three tables per document
    chem_tables.append(tables[i])
    name_tables.append(tables[i + 1].find(text = "IUPAC").findNext('td').get_text(",", strip = True))
    org_tables.append(tables[i + 2].findAll("i"))
    results_tables.append(tables[i + 2].findAll("i").findNext('td'))
```

Which is nice in that now `chem_tables[0]`, `org_tables[0]` and `name_tables[0]` all reference one drug, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the individual organism names out of `org_tables` without losing information about which drug their associated with...

I've been banging my head against the wall on this problem for 2 days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make my approach like this:

1) Find the `IUPAC` cell;

2) Get the value;

3) From the `IUPAC`cell find the nearest table;

4) Find all that table rows and skip the first two and the last one (Useless data);

5) For each row in the second row cell find all the `font` tags for the `Organism` values and;

6) Get each value from the third row cell to get the `MIC`values;

7) Get each value from 5) and store into a list

8) Split 6) by the comma and store into a list

9) Join everything in a dictionary;

Example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.trimslabs.com/mic/300.htm')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

MicDatabase = []

for IUPAC in soup.find_all(text="IUPAC"):
    Value = IUPAC.find_next('td').get_text(",", strip = True)

    for tr in IUPAC.find_next('table').find_all("tr")[2:-1]:
        td = tr.find_all("td")[1:]

        Organism = td[0].find_all("font")
        MIC = td[1].get_text(",", strip = True)

    MicDatabase.append(
        {
            "IUPAC": Value,
            "ActivityData": {"Organism": [o.get_text(" ", strip=True) for o in Organism], "MIC": MIC.split(',')}
        })
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'ActivityData': {'MIC': [u'2-4', u'1-2', u'1-2', u'1-2', u'2-4', u'2-4', u'2-4', u'1-2', u'>16', u'2-4', u'1-2', u'0.25 - 0.5', u'0.25 - 0.5'], 'Organism': [u'B. pumilus ATCC 14348', u'S. epidermidis ATCC 155', u'E. faecalis ATCC 35550', u'S. aureus ATCC 25923', u'S. aureus ATCC 9144', u'S. aureus ATCC 14154', u'S. aureus ATCC 29213', u'S. aureus ATCC 700699', u'(methicillin-resistant)', u'S. aureus NRS 119', u'(linezolid-resistant)', u'E.faecalis ATCC 14506', u'E.faecalis ATCC 700802', u'(vancomycin-resistant)', u'S.pyogenes ATCC 14289', u'S.pneumoniae ATCC 700904', u'(penicillin-resistant)']}, 'IUPAC': u'2-[(S)-3-(3-Fluoro-4-morpholin-4-yl-phenyl)-2-oxo-oxazolidin-5-yl]-acetamide'}...
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'm pretty new to this so the example code and explicit steps are very helpful!